# Ruby on Rails Meta Programming - Defining a class method using a dynamic array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, railscasts, class-method

I'm trying to use the meta programming example code in RailsCast #345 (Hstore) and replace the static array with one generated from another (unrelated) Model in the application.  The code sample from Ryan is:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :category, :price, :description

  # store_accessor :properties, :author

  %w[author rating runtime].each do |key|
    attr_accessible key

    define_method(key) do
      properties && properties[key]
    end

    define_method("#{key}=") do |value|
      self.properties = (properties || {}).merge(key => value)
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to replace `%w[author rating runtime]` above with something like `Foo.pluck(:content).map(&:downcase)` but that doesn't work.  I get a method undefined error when I try to access the dynamic methods. For example when calling

```
@product.send(foo.content.downcase) # <-- which returns "author"
```

I get:

```
undefined method `author' for #<Product:0x007ff111df0908>
```

It works fine using the static array.

Is it possible to replace that static array? I'd like to read those values from another model that an administrator populates and not have to touch the code for new values.  Open to alternative ways to accomplish the same thing too! Thanks for your time.

Comment: So your `Foo.pluck(:content).map(&:downcase)` produces the expected output when you try it in the console but produces nothing when it is executed when your `Product` class is being loaded? There's always `method_missing` as a backup.

Comment: Yes. It generates the proper array in the console but the Product.send(..) doesn't work unless the array is hardcoded. I will look at method_missing but I assumed that it should be a last resort (or backup as you say).  thanks

Comment: What specific error report do you get?  Have you tried requiring the file containing Foo?

Comment: updated the question with the error i get only when the array is not hardcoded.  I've tried adding require 'foo' in the Product class and I got the same result. thanks.

Comment: I'd guess that there is no database available when Ruby is loading your `Product` class: no database means no `Foo`s means no methods created. AFAIK, ActiveRecord uses `method_missing` to generate the attribute methods the first time `method_missing` is called.

Comment: yes. i've tried messing with initialize but you are probably correct mu.  i'll go down that path and see how far i get. thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `method_missing` in `activerecord-.../lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb`, I'd say more but I'm a busy with dinner ATM.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that array [author, rating, runtime] arent the columns from Product class. They are defined as attributes to class Product. Did you tried by replacing L#7 from " attr_accessible key " to " attr_accessor key " ?

Thanks.